# how to fix web server on ubuntu 16.04 LTS 500 eror when run script php?

Tags: php, webserver

I use LAMP as a web server, why do I get 500 error when I am wrong in just writing php code? Although only a few mistakes.
example: `<php if($blabla){ echo "superhero";` I just forgot to close it but why direct 500 error?
`

Answer (score 2):

My understanding is [HTTP response code 500](http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E500.html) is like a generic error code that relates to your HTML page. If you want error codes relating to your PHP code then perhaps best to run your code through a PHP compatible IDE or even from the command line `php myapp.php`